# Electricity supplication

Tags: electricity

Is their any reason I can search up as to why electricity is generally harder to inaugurate in regions of vast inhabitability?

Comment: I don't think it has got anything to do with physics.

Comment: @Yashbhatt can you explain why not?

Comment: For islands alternative energy like wind and solar become viable, even without subsidies, if one really wants electricity and is willing to install the infrastructure. At the moment a number of greek islands have independent generators supplied with oil  and some have wind turbines

Comment: @relentless See LDC3's answer. And I think it's nothing to do with physics because physical laws still work in remote areas.

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly economics. To install miles of power lines and the transformers at the destination costs the power company a significant amount. If there are enough customers at the destination to recover the expenditure, then the power lines will probably be installed.

Comment: What about environmental concerns? Such as in Antarctica, will that also make it more difficult?

Comment: @relentless Running power lines in extreme environments would increase costs since the environment can damage the infrastructure (see link at end). Antarctica would be a poor location since there are not enough customers. Currently, the camps bring their own power generators so it would be pointless to build a large generating falcility. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_storm#mediaviewer/File:Ice_storm.jpg